# How to fix dysfunctional pagination?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

Something is wrong with this [`alphabetical_paginate` gem](https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate) & I can't figure out how to fix it. I'm assuming this is not how it is suppose to look (I added the background color):

[image]

I'm assuming the letters are suppose to show horizontally:

```
All A P
```

And I know something is wrong because whatever letter(s) come after A are unclickable. A user can only click "All" or "A", I only have two users in this pagination, let's call them "Anthony" & "Paul".

**controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users, @alphaParams = User.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter]){|user| user.name}
  end

  ...
end
```

**users/index**

```
<%= alphabetical_paginate @alphaParams %>

<div id="pagination_table">
  <%= render @users %>
</div>
```

**assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( stat.js )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( habit.js )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( alphabetical_paginate.js )
```

What do you think the cause is? Please don't hesitate to ask for further code or clarification.

Comment: Can you try removing the `render` inside `<div id="pagination_table">` ? This may not solve all the problems but as per the gem Readme I see that is how it is being done. And which version of rails are you using?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna removing render had no affect :/ I'm using `Rails 4.2.0.rc3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added CSS class

```
  def index
    @users, @alphaParams = User.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
  end
```

CSS

```
.pagination-centered {
  li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: -1px;
  a {
    color: #446CB3;
  }
  }
  li.active {
    background-color: #446CB3;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Is everything working after this? I guess this should fix only the horizontal vertical issue. Moreover the gem has no support for Rails 4. Check this issue [here](https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate/issues/18)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna that explains why I had so much difficult. With my answer though it does make it horizontal, fixes the CSS to look like twitter-bootstrap pagination, and now all the letters are clickable :]